# What is the measure of $\measuredangle x$ in the figure below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, angle

For reference: In the figure shown P and Q are points of tangency and $ \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{BC}+\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{FE}=130^o. $
Calculate "x".

[image]

My progress:

I think the starting point would be the interior angle theorem

$ \measuredangle BIC = \frac{\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{BC}+\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{FE}}{2}=\frac{130}{2}=65^\circ \implies \measuredangle BIF = 115^\circ \\
\triangle BDF(isosceles) \\
\triangle ACE(isoscels)\\
\measuredangle IBF=\measuredangle IFB = \measuredangle ICE = \measuredangle IEC=\frac{65^o}{2}$

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

$\angle BAC + \angle FAE = 65^0$

$\angle PAQ = \frac{\angle POQ}{2} = 90^\circ - \frac{x}{2}$

$\angle BAF + \angle BDF = 180^\circ$

$\implies 65^\circ + 90^\circ - \frac{x}{2} + x = 180^\circ$

$\implies  x = 50^\circ$

Comment: Very good ..only when you do $∠BAC + ∠FAE = 65^o$, do you use any properties?

Comment: I think I understand... inscribed angles are worth half the central angle

Comment: @petaarantes yes inscribed angles are half of central angles. That's all I used there.

Comment: yes I realized later...thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

Let $\measuredangle PQD=y$.

Thus, $$2y+x=180^{\circ}.$$

In another hand, since $ACDE$ is cyclic, we obtain:
$$y+x+\measuredangle CDB+\measuredangle FDE=180^{\circ}$$ or
$$y+x+65^{\circ}=180^{\circ}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $x=50^{\circ}.$